# Why can't i checkout a new branch?

Tags: git, version-control, github, branch

So I get into terminal and for some reason I am on a branch that I don't remember making:

```
camel@therafer:~/hashrocket/poopgraph(ref: re...)
```

When I try to get out of this branch by using `gco master` it tells me:

```
camel@therafer:~/hashrocket/poopgraph(ref: re...)$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb
    app/models/user.rb
    features/dump.feature

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

So I go on to try and stash or commit the branch, commiting doesn't seem to do anything because when i do git status there are still a bunch of new files that pop up, and stash just returns:

```
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
fatal: Needed a single revision
You do not have the initial commit yet
```

This is driving me crazy because I just keep going in circles and I can't seem to figure out why my branch system isn't working.

Note: i also tried changing the HEAD branch as suggested by another similar post and that did not work.

Comment: There might be some unversion files which you need to commit or stash before moving to another branch.

Comment: funny thing about that i believe that i stated that i tried stashing or committing and neither is working please elaborate on how I am supposed to do something that doesn't work.

Comment: stash mean delete the unversion files

Comment: if you want to commit the unversion file, then you need to use git add as mentioned by Gab

Answer (score 1):

Well I was able to get in touch with someone more experienced and luckily he had a simple solution.He told me to run:

```
    hcd

    rm -rf poopgraph

    git clone git@github.com:mrmicahcooper/poopgraph.git
```

This takes me out of the project, then removes the project from my computer, the last command simply adds it back onto my computer from the online server github. Apparently the problem was a technical error that must have been the result of some freak accident, and it was not a normal programming error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git add .       //add all files to the staging area including unversioned filed
git commit -m "commit message"     //Commit
```

This will add all files to the staging area and then commit them.

Or, if you want to lose all your changes, you could also do the following :

```
git checkout -- .  //checkout the last version of all files
```

Then try to

```
git checkout branchName
```

Comment: AS i stated before, i have already been doing that and it won't work. I have been using the commit and git checkout for a while now and i know what im saying when i say that neither of these work even after i do "git add .

Answer (score -1):

use below command

**git checkout -b branchname origin**

only add your branch name on place of `branchname`